# How to speed up query with a WHERE IN (...)?

Tags: mysql

I have this query into MYSQL, I have indexes everywhere, but answer from DB I have in 0.1 - 0.15 sec and it's too much because I need to have more queries there and to have 0.5 sec of total execution is too much. I know that trouble will be WHERE IN, but how to speed it up when I have only that datas? Table bases is about 30 000 lines.

```
SELECT 
      sklad_dodavatelu.Mnozstvi_Skladem as PocetSklademUdodavatele,
      bases.Objednaci_nazev, 
      bases.Id_Pohoda,
      bases.Kod,
      bases.Dodani,
      bases.StavSkladem,
      bases.StavObjednano,
      bases.Stav_obj_dod, 
      bases.StavSkladem - bases.StavObjednano as Count_Free, 
      bases.Nazev, 
      bases.Dodavatel, 
      vyrobci_web.UsualDeliveryTime, 
      bases.Predpoklad_Doruceni, 
      bases.NaseNaskladneni,
      bases.CenaInternet, 
      bases.Akce, 
      bases.Text, 
      druhy_zbozi.Vip, 
      druhy_zbozi.Druh, 
      pictures.Url, 
      pictures.Popis, 
      pictures.Barva, 
      rel_zasoby.Kod_hlavicka, 
      sklad_dodavatelu.Naskladneni, 
      hlavicky.Nazev as NazevHlavicky, 
      sklad_dodavatelu.IdDodavatele, 
      (SELECT Datum 
          FROM ppl 
          order by Datum desc 
          limit 1) as PosledniPPL, 
      adb.MaxOdeslaniZbozi, 
      adb.OcekavaneZboziSkladem, 
      (SELECT Hodnota 
          from konstanty 
          where nazev = 'MaxPPL' 
          limit 1) as KonstantaPPL
   from 
      bases 
         LEFT JOIN sklad_dodavatelu 
            on bases.Objednaci_nazev = sklad_dodavatelu.Id_Produktu
         LEFT JOIN rel_zasoby 
            on bases.Id_Pohoda = rel_zasoby.Kod_Pohoda 
            LEFT JOIN hlavicky 
               on rel_zasoby.Kod_hlavicka = hlavicky.Id_Pohoda 
               LEFT JOIN vyrobci_web 
                  on hlavicky.Vyrobce = vyrobci_web.Nazev 
            LEFT JOIN hlavicky_druhy 
               on rel_zasoby.Kod_hlavicka = hlavicky_druhy.Id_hlavicky
               LEFT JOIN druhy_zbozi 
                  on hlavicky_druhy.Id_druh = druhy_zbozi.Id
         LEFT join pictures 
            on bases.Kod = pictures.Kod
         LEFT join adb 
            on bases.Dodavatel = adb.adb_number_ids
   where 
      bases.Id_Pohoda in 
         ( '42735', '13979', '43069', '61283', '64303', '61271', '56462',
           '41507', '31348', '60963', '62136', '69403', '43071', '13828',
           '43073', '61281', '64310', '64306', '64307', '71453', '64514',
           '79025', '79026', '44797', '77095', '77094', '55214', '76804',
           '76806', '76805', '35490', '16432', '15072', '10416', '15101',
           '7453', '13359', '16539', '16540', '34044', '44817', '61523',
           '45969', '45963', '71065', '73430', '73425', '73427', '73426',
           '73424', '73428', '73429', '73423', '30978', '32959', '33171',
           '30918', '33233', '66308', '66309', '44795', '55251', '76074',
           '76073', '67208', '67210', '67211', '49056', '49055', '49053',
           '49048', '49054', '49047', '49061', '49062', '49063', '49064',
           '49066', '49067', '49068', '49070', '55390', '55391', '55392',
           '55393', '55394', '62580', '62581', '62257', '60674', '80803',
           '56539', '79064', '79065', '79063', '79066', '81772', '81774',
           '81773', '81777', '52901', '52902', '52900', '52898', '60345',
           '54549', '76095', '76096', '76097', '67227', '67226', '67228',
           '53419', '53418', '73433', '73438', '73435', '73434', '73431',
           '73432', '73436', '73437', '72722', '72713', '56254', '56255',
           '56256', '56257', '56258', '56259', '56260', '56261', '56246',
           '56247', '56248', '56249', '56250', '56251', '56252', '56253',
           '56292', '69042', '69044', '69046', '69048', '69049', '57227',
           '57230', '57231', '57232', '57233', '57228', '57229', '57525',
           '62260', '62261', '80481', '80482', '80483', '80478', '80479',
           '80484', '80480', '57518', '57519', '57517', '57220', '57222',
           '58632', '58630', '58631', '58628', '58637', '58634', '58636',
           '58635', '58633', '58647', '58644', '58646', '58645', '58643',
           '58642', '58639', '58641', '58640', '58638', '60459', '60938',
           '60942', '60944', '60945', '77608', '60787', '60708', '60709',
           '62550', '76619', '76620', '76618', '60405', '60404', '66974',
           '80598', '80596', '80594', '80595', '80597', '60978', '60979',
           '60980', '60981', '60982', '60983', '60985', '60988', '60989',
           '60966', '60967', '60968', '60969', '60990', '60970', '60971',
           '60972', '60973', '60974', '60984', '61588', '61503', '61504',
           '55006', '55008', '55009', '55010', '55011', '55012', '55013',
           '55014', '55015', '55016', '55017', '55018', '61630', '61631',
           '61629', '61632', '61628', '61633', '61627', '61634', '61626',
           '61635', '61625', '61636', '61624', '61637', '61623', '61638',
           '61622', '61639', '61620', '61640', '61593', '61608', '61606',
           '61609', '61605', '61610', '61604', '61611', '61603', '61612',
           '61602', '61613', '61601', '61614', '61600', '61615', '61599',
           '61616', '61598', '61617', '61597', '61596', '61619', '61618',
           '61546', '61545', '61544', '61543', '61542', '61541', '61540',
           '61539', '61538', '61534', '61679', '61677', '61675', '67070',
           '67069', '61681', '62041', '62037', '62036', '62040', '62038',
           '62042', '69272', '69274', '69275', '81633', '81632', '81631',
           '76570', '76571', '76569', '76572', '76573', '62340', '62342',
           '62338', '62341', '62343', '62339', '70652', '70653', '70651',
           '64120', '64121', '64122', '64123', '64124', '64221', '64220',
           '64224', '64225', '64226', '64761', '64756', '76411', '76412',
           '76410', '76409', '79009', '79008', '79007', '79010', '79014',
           '79015', '79013', '79018', '79016', '79017', '79011', '79012',
           '71449', '66480', '66481', '66482', '66483', '66484', '66486',
           '73209', '79253', '79254', '66542', '66538', '66539', '66536',
           '66540', '74840', '79255', '79256', '66599', '72718', '72719',
           '73459', '73457', '77404', '66709', '66710', '66820', '66819',
           '66770', '66578', '67216', '67111', '67112', '67113', '67114',
           '67120', '67075', '67559', '73003', '68661', '81115', '81114',
           '68662', '81113', '81112', '67396', '67397', '67399', '67400',
           '67401', '72870', '72871', '67381', '67382', '67384', '67385',
           '67386', '72934', '72935', '67375', '67377', '67376', '67378',
           '67379', '67380', '72933', '72932', '67394', '67393', '67391',
           '67390', '67395', '72869', '72868', '68986', '68987', '68988',
           '76623', '68982', '68983', '76622', '76621', '69434', '74890',
           '64108', '70697', '70699', '70706', '70760', '70759', '70758',
           '70757', '70756', '70753', '70754', '70755', '80647', '80649',
           '80650', '80651', '80648', '70587', '81085', '81086', '71494',
           '81088', '81087', '72658', '72659', '72666', '72660', '72661',
           '72664', '72667', '72665', '76537', '77610', '77612', '77611',
           '77613', '77615', '77614', '81634', '81891', '81892', '81893',
           '81895', '81894', '81896', '67115', '72957', '67072', '67562',
           '73112', '73113', '73255', '73254', '73252', '73250', '73251',
           '73253', '73261', '73260', '73258', '73256', '73257', '73259',
           '73224', '77555', '77552', '77556', '77553', '77554', '74760',
           '74759', '74761', '74762', '80952', '74822', '74821', '74823',
           '74825', '74826', '76485', '74903', '76076', '76075', '76105',
           '76106', '76103', '76104', '76089', '76090', '76091', '76092',
           '76381', '76379', '76380', '76624', '76625', '76626', '80870',
           '80869', '80868', '80867', '76941', '76940', '76944', '76943',
           '76942', '76463', '76464', '76465', '76466', '76467', '76468',
           '76950', '76951', '76952', '76948', '76949', '80766', '80767',
           '80768', '80764', '80765', '76997', '76947', '76945', '76946',
           '81201', '81202', '79019', '79023', '79021', '79024', '79020',
           '79022', '76715', '76716', '76717', '76719', '76718', '81816',
           '81817', '81818', '81755', '81756', '77093', '78952', '78950',
           '78947', '78949', '78953', '78951', '78948', '79068', '79067',
           '79069', '77002', '79143', '79153', '79154', '79140', '79141',
           '79142', '79155', '79080', '79139', '79148', '79157', '79144',
           '79159', '79158', '79145', '79146', '79147', '79135', '79152',
           '79160', '79162', '79161', '79149', '79151', '79150', '79136',
           '79137', '79004', '79005', '79006', '77887', '77884', '77885',
           '77886', '80774', '74713', '74714', '80459', '80455', '80458',
           '76486', '81007', '81008', '81523', '81525', '80580', '76237',
           '77104', '77004', '80563', '80561', '80562', '80568', '80569',
           '80567', '80698', '80704', '80699', '80703', '80697', '80700',
           '80706', '80705', '81277', '79176', '79177', '79178', '79183',
           '79184', '79185', '80749', '80739', '80751', '80736', '80737',
           '80735', '81321', '81834', '80831', '79277', '79275', '79287',
           '79288', '79276', '79274', '79250', '79289', '79286', '79263',
           '79258', '79257', '79264', '79260', '79262', '79259', '79261',
           '79234', '79269', '79273', '79272', '79270', '79265', '79268',
           '74842', '79267', '79271', '79295', '79296', '80858', '79293',
           '79290', '79292', '79297', '79291', '79294', '80928', '80930',
           '80929', '80931', '81016', '81076', '81074', '81567', '81565',
           '81566', '81570', '81569', '81568', '81238', '81240', '81239',
           '67407', '81249', '81315', '81319', '81320', '81314', '81316',
           '81247', '81248', '81551', '81550', '81555', '81554', '81552',
           '80755', '80756', '80757', '80758', '80759', '80760', '81776',
           '81775', '81806', '81808', '81823', '81822', '81821', '81820',
           '81786', '81792', '81789', '81795', '81790', '81791', '81793',
           '81794', '81787', '81785', '81784', '81788', '82018', '82019',
           '82020', '81761', '81764', '77595', '81766', '81767', '81760',
           '82213', '82214', '82206', '82207', '82243', '82247', '82245',
           '82248', '82246') 
   order by 
      bases.Nazev, 
      bases.Id_Pohoda
```

Comment: Please include the result of the explain in your question!

Comment: Check the explain of the query and add indexes on columns that it suggests.

WHERE .. IN will be slow if there is no index on `bases.Id_Pohoda` but that is as for any other compare operation.

Comment: Table bases is about 30 000 lines - is that unique Id_Pohoda(s)?

Comment: test this: remove joins from your query and just run the where in query without order on a subquery inside () then use the result of your subquery to join it with other tables this might help.
if its still slow remove the where clause and use UNION for each id and get the result inside of a subquery then join with other tables and order the result

Comment: Hello,
thanks for answers.
Here is explain: https://www.kocarky.cz/exp.jpg

Comment: Yes. For Id_Pohoida there is index and it's unique.

Comment: Try to save your values list into indexed temptable and join it in your query.

Answer (score 1):

After cleaning up your query for readability and what others may not have seen because of it, there are many things to consider.

First, your IN clause has almost 800 IDs.  How did you come up with all these IDs.  IF it was from a query of some condition AND you built the string query out, that is a problem.  You would be best to change to something like

```
SELECT
     all, your, columns
   from
      ( select theId
           from YourTable
           where YourCondition ) PreQuery
         JOIN Bases b
            ON PreQuery.theId = bases.IdColumn
```

Also, if your "ID" values are actually numeric values (integer), dont wrap 'quotes' around them.  They are numbers, no need to interpret numbers from a string, leave them as numbers WITHOUT quotes.

Next, you have two column-based queries which are not correlated to any specific base or other child table. This is doing the query every time against ALL records. I would add this to the JOIN list of tables since it is always returning a single row anyhow and just grab it.  However, if it IS supposed to be associated WITH a specific ID of some other context, that needs to be indicated/adjusted.

```
SELECT
      all, your, columns,
      Posledni.Datum as PosledniPPL,
      Konstanta.Hodnota as KonstantaPPL
   from
      bases
         JOIN (all your other joins)
         JOIN (SELECT Datum 
                   FROM ppl 
                   order by Datum desc 
                   limit 1) as Posledni 
         JOIN (SELECT Hodnota 
                   from konstanty 
                   where nazev = 'MaxPPL' 
                   limit 1) as Konstanta
```

Then on to indexes.  Having indexes on just a single column key does not help as much as a multi-column / covering helping, especially when joining nested levels.
Following suggested indexes

```
table             index
bases             ( Id_Pohoda, Nazev, Objednaci_nazev, Kod, Dodavatel )
sklad_dodavatelu  ( Id_Produktu )
rel_zasoby        ( Kod_Pohoda, Kod_hlavicka )
hlavicky          ( Id_Pohoda, Vyrobce )
vyrobci_web       ( Nazev )
hlavicky_druhy    ( Id_hlavicky, Id_druh )
druhy_zbozi       ( Id )
pictures          ( Kod )
adb               ( adb_number_ids )
```

Finally, as you write queries, and especially when getting into using the same table in the same query multiple times for alternate lookup purposes, using aliases vs long table names can help simplify vs overtyping.  So, without retyping your ENTIRE query, consider the following using aliases.

```
SELECT 
      s.Mnozstvi_Skladem as PocetSklademUdodavatele,
      b.Objednaci_nazev, 
      b.Id_Pohoda,
      b.Kod,
      b.StavSkladem - b.StavObjednano as Count_Free,       
      vw.UsualDeliveryTime,
      b.Predpoklad_Doruceni,
      dz.Vip, 
      dz.Druh, 
      p.Url, 
      p.Popis,       
      r.Kod_hlavicka, 
      s.Naskladneni,       
      h.Nazev as NazevHlavicky
   from 
      bases b
         LEFT JOIN sklad_dodavatelu s
            on b.Objednaci_nazev = s.Id_Produktu
         LEFT JOIN rel_zasoby r
            on b.Id_Pohoda = r.Kod_Pohoda 
            LEFT JOIN hlavicky h
               on r.Kod_hlavicka = h.Id_Pohoda 
               LEFT JOIN vyrobci_web vw
                  on h.Vyrobce = vw.Nazev 
            LEFT JOIN hlavicky_druhy hd 
               on r.Kod_hlavicka = hd.Id_hlavicky
               LEFT JOIN druhy_zbozi dz
                  on hd.Id_druh = dz.Id
         LEFT join pictures p
            on b.Kod = p.Kod
         LEFT join adb 
            on b.Dodavatel = adb.adb_number_ids
   where 
      b.Id_Pohoda in ( your list of 800+ IDs)
   order by
      b.Nazev, 
      b.Id_Pohoda
```